# how to close client socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets

After connection is established with client,if data not received for some time how to close client connection?

```
public class Server_X_Client {
public static void main(String args[]){


Socket s=null;
ServerSocket ss2=null;
System.out.println("Server Listening......");
try{
    ss2 = new ServerSocket(4445); // can also use static final PORT_NUM , when defined
ss2.setSoTimeout(5000);
}
catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Server error");

}

while(true){
    try{
        s= ss2.accept();
        System.out.println("connection Established with --> "+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);
        st.start();

    }

catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Connection Error");

}
}

}

}
```

class ServerThread extends Thread{

```
String line=null;
BufferedReader  is = null;
PrintWriter os=null;
Socket s=null;

public ServerThread(Socket s){
    this.s=s;
}

public void run() {
try{
    is= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
//
    os=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("IO error in server thread");
}

try {
    line=is.readLine();

    while(line.compareTo("QUIT")!=0){

        os.println(line);
        os.flush();
    System.out.println("Data recieved is : "+ line);

        line=is.readLine();
    }   
} catch (IOException e) {

    line=this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
    System.out.println("IO Error/ Client "+line+" terminated abruptly");
}
catch(NullPointerException e){
    line=this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
    System.out.println("Client "+line+" Closed");
}

finally{    
try{
    System.out.println("Connection Closing..");
    if (is!=null){
        is.close(); 
        System.out.println(" Socket Input Stream Closed");
    }

    if(os!=null){
        os.close();
        System.out.println("Socket Out Closed");
    }
    if (s!=null){
    s.close();
    System.out.println("Socket Closed");
    }

    }
catch(IOException ie){
    System.out.println("Socket Close Error");
}
}//end finally
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setSoTimeOut(int timeout)` function . See here [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) how to use `setSoTimeOut` function.

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: I did it earlier but , it continuously printing " socket exception"

Comment: what time you gave inside setSoTimeOut() function?

Comment: ss2.setSoTimeout(10000);

Comment: that means if data is not received in time, then you should close the socket inside catch block of the exception.

Comment: you can use but both are same